# How to submit EMR job in cluster mode having application master on ondemand CORE node

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

From AWS documentation it is possible to use CORE and TASK nodes.

It is possible to configure application master to start on CORE node.
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-instances-guidelines.html#emr-plan-spot-YARN

Is it possible to configure EMR to prefer **ondemand** CORE node for application master in case when I have both **spot** and **ondemand** CORE nodes?

Comment: No, master node must be a master node.

Comment: @jordanm, I mean application master and not master node. Application master is where the driver process is started.